# How to update SetContentView (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am a beginning of Android Programming, i am wring a SMS sending program today.
The program like this:

[image: pict1]

After clicking the Sent button, 
The results will shown like above:

[image: pictw]

But may I shown the results below the send button, like the following one ?
[image: pictw]

Here is the java code of front page :

```
public class sms extends Activity {

Button sendButton;
EditText phoneTextField;
EditText msgTextField;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.smslay);        

    msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    phoneTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneTextField);

}
```

Comment: Yes, just add one textview below to send button and update text when ever you want..

Comment: post your smslay.xml or add one textview below the send button.

Answer (score 0):

Just take one textview below to send button. After you got result just set text to that textview. When user will again click on send button set that text to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a toast message http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html 
Instead of edittext or vise versa